# Oracle WebCenter - can't edit assets

Tags: oracle, webcenter, webcenter-sites

I get the following error message when I try to edit assets:

> You can't modify this asset, as it has been scheduled for publishing. Please try again after the publish operation has completed. If this condition persists, please contact your system administrator.

Also, when I try to remove these assets from the Publishing Queue (Publishing>Select Destination>Assets ready to be published>Unapprove), I get the following error message:

> Cannot unapprove deleted assets.

Has anyone encountered these issues and found a solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try to purge voided assets ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not normally possible to see deleted assets in the UI, so it seems there may be some corruption. As a workaround you can use SitesExplorer or a db tool (squirrel, sqlplus, etc), to change the cs_status column on the affected asset(s) from 'VO' to 'ED'. Then you can try again to remove them from the publish queue.